# CUDA & Python for numerical integration and solving differential equations

Tags: python, integration, differential-equations, cuda

Can anyone please suggest some libraries which allow use CUDA in Python for numerical integration and/or solving of differential equations?

My goal is to solve large (~1000 equations) of coupled non-linear ordinary differential equations and I would like to use CUDA for it.

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-python

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Julia's [DifferentialEquations.jl](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/) is all GPU-compatible. If you make your arrays GPU-based arrays, then the solver recompiles to be all on the GPU (no data transfers). For example:

```
using OrdinaryDiffEq, CUDA, LinearAlgebra
u0 = cu(rand(1000))
A  = cu(randn(1000,1000))
f(du,u,p,t)  = mul!(du,A,u)
prob = ODEProblem(f,u0,(0.0f0,1.0f0)) # Float32 is better on GPUs!
sol = solve(prob,Tsit5())
```

is all GPU-based. You can make use of this from Python via [diffeqpy](https://github.com/SciML/diffeqpy). There's not much nice syntax exposing GPU usage to Python right now, but you could use the following to do the same:

```
import diffeqpy
diffeqpy.install()
from diffeqpy import de

sol = Main.eval("""
    using CUDA, LinearAlgebra
    u0 = cu(rand(1000))
    A  = cu(randn(1000,1000))
    f(du,u,p,t)  = mul!(du,A,u)
    prob = ODEProblem(f,u0,(0.0f0,1.0f0)) # Float32 is better on GPUs!
    sol = solve(prob,Tsit5())
    Array(sol) # Return an array
""")
```

Note that this requires CUDA is installed on your Julia installation.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that people use

- [CuPy](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/index.html); and
- [scikit-cuda](https://scikit-cuda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

But, I don't see that any of those provide differential equations capabilities.

Looking around, I found [CudaPyInt](https://pythonhosted.org/CudaPyInt/index.html) and it uses [PyCuda](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/).